# Where is 'Top Level of the Application Bundle'? in XCode

Tags: iphone

I am trying to place the Default.png image into my iPhone App, yet can't figure out where the 'top level of the application bundle' is in the XCode window. Do you not add it to Xcode, and instead into the Build file before you zip it to release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to your project. You can put it in any group "folder" (e.g. "Resources").

Answer (score 0):

Your "top level of the application bundle" is the directory where your `Info.plist` file resides.